# Add text on different position on the images in Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I have an image view. I need to display the various text on images.For each image the position of the text gets differ.I will give position value using x,y co ordinates of `ImageView`.

Any guesses How to perform this?

Comment: can we have some code please !?

Comment: I dont have any code. I'm new to android.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a bitmap
2. Create a canvas
3. Draw what you need
4. Post it to the imageview

Like this:

```
Bitmap drawingSurface = Bitmap.createBitmap(picBitmap.getWidth(), picBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(drawingSurface);
canvas.drawBitmap(picBitmap, 0, 0, null);

canvas.drawText("Hi!", 10, 10, new Paint());

myImageView.setImageBitmap(drawingSurface);
```

Comment: i need to add some buttons also, is it possible?

Comment: You can set an image as the background of a button if you need to do it the same way. Otherwise the button has a text property.

Comment: No i need to place a overlay on the image with few text and button on different positions.

Comment: Buttons will be harder if you do this solution. I would implement them as touch areas, and then monitor onTouch to see what the user presses

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulate the image and text in a layout then give coordinates to the views inside their parrent then use theencapsulated view group like your imageview.

Answer (score -1):

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    options.inScaled=false;
                    Bitmap original;
                    Bitmap mutable = null;
                    try{
                    original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.,null);
                    mutable = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    Paint paint=new Paint();
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    Canvas c= new Canvas(mutable);
                    Log.d("density",""+dm.density);
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    paint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);   
                    paint.setTextSize(42);
                    c.drawText("text", (mutable.getWidth()/2)-x,(mutable.getHeight()/2)+y, paint);
                    BitmapDrawable bitmap = new BitmapDrawable(mutable)

                    imageView set background drawable bitmap
```